# A small part of my transcript is hard to read; can I get into trouble?

Tags: graduate-school, application, transcript-of-records, translations

My university does not provide official transcripts in English, so I sent mine to a certified translator for translation. There is a footer on each page in Persian, and unfortunately, on one page, this footer covers the cumulative GPA and total passed credits of a summer semester; it is not unreadable but hard to read.

[image: Footer covers Cumulative GPA and Total Passed Credits.]

Since December 15 is the deadline of some of the universities I want to apply for, there is no time for me to ask for another certified translated transcript. Do you think applying with this transcript might be a problem?

Comment: Surely asking someone to fix a poor layout on the transcript they provided you is reasonable and quicker than asking for a new one? I'd at least ask first.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- This transcript is certified, signed, and sealed by the ministry of foreign affairs. In order to get another, the translator can fix the layout in a few minutes, but I do have to post my original transcript again for the ministry, and it takes at least ten days for the sign and seal.

Comment: Oh that's a bummer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply with this transcript and to be on the safe side make sure you mention your grades (especially the parts that are hard to read) somewhere else where they are easy to read. In this case, someone who wants to 'confirm' your declaration can 'easily' (or with a little effort) check with the image you showed.

Perhaps also provide the originals? I am assuming the grades will be in the same numerals so at least the numbers can be read.